# C++ and OpenCV: InputArrayOfArrays Type and reconstruct() function in SfM Module

Tags: c++, opencv, structure-from-motion

I am experimenting with the SfM Module in `opencv_contrib`, and I was reading the documentation for the [reconstruct()](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/db5/group__reconstruction.html) function. I'm a bit confused as to one of the parameters that I can pass to it.

One of the arguments is:

`InputArrayOfArrays     points2d`

and that's defined as:

`points2d   Input vector of vectors of 2d points (the inner vector is per image).`

Does that mean we flatten the Mat data type of each image into a vector of vectors or something? I don't get it.

Do I need to use a feature matcher and find matching features, then put those features in this vector?

Either I'm not understanding what it means properly, or the documentation is a bit confusing. I'm rather new to OpenCV in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `std::vector` too, matching that definition. Or have a 2 channel `cv::Mat`, where each row holds points for one image.

Comment: @DanMašek Can I "flatten" a `Mat Image;` into a vector of points instead? Then aggregate them together into a single vector?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean by that -- can you elaborate? If something is called an "image", I'd expect it to be a 2d array of pixels, each pixel representing some colour. A Point2D represents a position (coordinates). I understand "flatten" to mean reducing the array into a single dimension, and I don't see how this process could turn colours into positions.